# Hijri DatePicker in Xamarin Forms (specifically IOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show Hijri calendar in DatePicker in Xamarin Forms proj but I couldn't .

I changed language on the device to Arabic and added this code in Main function as follow :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
```

I also tried to use Custom renderer to force the control to use Arabic date but it didn't have any effect like this :

```
public class MyDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var datePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
        datePicker.Locale = new Foundation.NSLocale(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    }
}
```

I tried all this on the simulator if that makes any difference .

Now , Is there anything else I should try or is it hard to achieve ?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added language codes to section CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist file and added setting mideast as well in the config but also to no avail .

Comment: have you tried this             datePicker.Calendar = new NSCalendar(NSCalendarType.IslamicUmmAlQura);